# Strapi 3 Beta.17.5 did not create any table in the mysql database

Tags: strapi

the project I created with Strapi 3 Beta.17.5 did not create any table in the mysql database. During the installation but no error was displayed. What could be the problem?

Please see screenshot!

Thanks in advance

B. L.

[image]
[image]

Comment: And after starting it?

Comment: Yes, but without any table, the project can not be started. :(

Comment: Haven't been able to reproduce...

Comment: Could the new Node.js be a problem? I have installed Node.js v13.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The SSL was set to "true". After I changed it to "false", the project runs and has also created tables. :)

What I do not understand yet is that I entered "No" for SSL during installation, and SSL still set to "true".

Comment: Fancy explaining how you set SSL to false?